# Complex date trouble in powerbi

Tags: date, multidimensional-array, powerbi, slicers

I don't figure out how to manage my problem with a unique simple date slicer.

I have a table with contracts begin and end date joined with a dimensional table Dates.
I would like to count contracts over the period using this slicer.
I would like to create an unique slicer with a time range using my Date dimensional table.

[image: slicer]

This slicer should select in my table all contracts (eg):

- Started before 04/01/2017 and finished after the 04/01/2017.
- Started before 04/01/2017 but not finished after 08/01/2017.
- Started during period but not finished in this period.
- Started and finished in this period.

Any idea how i should do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, in this particular case, I would remove relationship between Date and contracts tables. The way relationships work is they limit resultset (rows) in the filtered table (on the `many` side of the relationship) to contain rows matchin exactly those values that are currently selected in the filtering table (on the `one` side of the relationship).

This is clearly not what you want, because:

- you want to filter based on more than one column
- you want a more complex filtering logic

After you've removed the relationship, all you have to do is:

```
How many contracts =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        Contracts,
        NOT (
            Contracts[start_date] > MAX ( Dates[date] )
                || Contracts[end_date] < MIN ( Dates[date] )
        )
    )
)
```

This is a simpler way to select contracts, as it requires only two conditions. This is simply saying that you don't want to see contracts (`NOT`) that end before the selected date range or start after it, which covers all the cases you described.